# infinite intersection of 2 uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that if the intersection of 2 uncountable sets is infinite, then the intersection is definitely uncountable?

How do I start disproving/ proving this statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

False: Construct 2 sets: $A=\mathbb{N}\cup(0,1), B=\mathbb{N}\cup(2,3)$.

Comment: I think the OP wants both sets to be uncountable.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is uncountable, so $\mathbb{N}\cup(0,1)$ is also uncountable. @user99680

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true. Take $A=[-\infty,0)$ and $B=[0,\infty) \cup ${$-1,-2,-3,....$}, then $A\cap B$ is the negative integers, which are countable.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A:=[0,1]$, $B:=\{n^{-1},n\in\mathbb N\}\cup[1,2]$. Both $A$ and $B$ are uncountable, their intersection is the infinite countable set $\{n^{-1},n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{1\}$.